# I found this error Warning: validateDOMNesting(...): <a> cannot appear as a descendant of <a>.how can i resolved it?

Tags: reactjs

I've done a react project recently. and faced this warning. could not figure out the problem. There is a screenshot attached about that warning

Answer (score 1):

It's basically saying you have an `<a>` inside another `<a>`

```
<a>
  <a>Some link</a>
</a>
```

You have to find it.
We will need more clue in order to help.

Wild guess, do you use `react-router-dom` and maybe do something like this? If yes, you can remove the inner `<a>`, because react-router-dom's `<Link>` is already an `<a>`

```
<Link to="/somepage">
  <a>Some page</a>
</Link>
```

Answer (score 0):

The warning is telling you everything you need to know, don't put an `<a>` tag inside of another `<a>` tag.